# How to get custom delegate to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, delegates

I am creating a custom delegate  UIAlertView's `alert:buttonClickedAtIndex:` method, but it is not working properly. I am subclassing a UIView, and I have two buttons that are tagged as `0` and `1`. This still does not work when I go to check the delegate for my custom view. Here  the code  that I did.

Custom View

```
- (void) buttonTouchedWithIdentifier:(NSInteger)identifier
{
if (identifier == 0) {
    [self.delegate alert:self didClickButtonWithTagIdentifier:0];
}
if (identifier == 1) {
    [self.delegate alert:self didClickButtonWithTagIdentifier:1];
}
}

* in my showInViewMethod *
[self.dismissButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouchedWithIdentifier:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.continueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouchedWithIdentifier:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

self.dismissButton.tag  = 0;
self.continueButton.tag = 1;



* in my view controller *

nextLevelAlert = [[ARAlert alloc] init];
nextLevelAlert.delegate = self;
[nextLevelAlert showInView:self.view
      withMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Congratulations, you have completed level %i.\nWould you like to continue?", levelNumber]
  dismissButtonTitle:@"Menu"
 continueButtonTitle:@"Next Level"];

- (void)alert:(ARAlert *)alert didClickButtonWithTagIdentifier:(NSInteger)tagId
{
    if (alert == nextLevelAlert) {
       if (tagId == 0) {
           NSLog(@"User does not want to continue.");
       }
    }
}
```

Now, nextLevelAlert has the delegate set to self, and I do have the delegate declared in my view controller's class. Also, when i do the showInView... for nextLevelAlert, it DOES appear, it is recognizing what button is being pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your param is not a NSInteger but the button, you should change `buttonTouchedWithIdentifier` like this :

```
- (void) buttonTouchedWithIdentifier:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"buttonTouchedWithIdentifier %@",@(button.tag));
    if (button.tag == 0) {
        [self.delegate alert:self didClickButtonWithTagIdentifier:0];
    }
    if (button.tag == 1) {
        [self.delegate alert:self didClickButtonWithTagIdentifier:1];
    }
}
```

Also when comparing two objects use `isEqual:` instead of `==`

```
- (void)alert:(ARAlert *)alert didClickButtonWithTagIdentifier:(NSInteger)tagId
{
    if ([alert isEqual:nextLevelAlert]) {
       if (tagId == 0) {
           NSLog(@"User does not want to continue.");
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I added what you said, and even changed it to where param on didClickButton...was button.tag, but nothing is changing

Comment: Do you reach the code inside buttonTouchedWithIdentifier ?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"buttonTouchedWithIdentifier %@",@(button.tag));` just below `UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;` and check the console if it prints something.